# CSS Background with svg duplicating multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, svg

I am trying to add a svg gradient background image to my website, however, When adding the SVG as a background it just seems to duplicate it multiple times randomly. I have never had this issue before when adding background images, not sure why it is not working now.
[image]

I have tried adding background no repeat on the line after. However this doesn't fix the issue.

```css
{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {

  background-image: url(./color-morph.svg);
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 35px;
  transition: .3s;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: black;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px white;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  border-right: 5px solid;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation:
    typing 2s steps(17),
    cursor .4s step-end infinite alternate;
}

/* cursor blinking effect */
@keyframes cursor {
  50% {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
}

/* Typewriter effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title>Website</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>

   <body>

     <header class="header">
       <a href="#" class="logo">Matt</a>

       <nav class="navbar">
         <a href="#">Home</a>
         <a href="#">About</a>
         <a href="#">Contact</a>
         <a href="#">Projects</a>
       </nav>
     </header>


     <div class="container">
       <p class="text">Hello, Matt Here.</p>
     </div>


   </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: `background-repeat: no-repeat` should fix this

Comment: @Tigger Kinda of it fixes the issue for desktop view, but if I try in mobile view it still repeats the image, and if I add background-repeat: no-repeat; after it just leave a bunch of white space under neath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must say that the image does not repeat itself and that it covers the entire screen

Try this : (updated)

```
 body {
      
      background-image: url(./color-morph.svg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

Comment: Kinda of fixes the issue for desktop view, but if I try in mobile view it still repeats the image, it just leave a bunch of white space under neath